# docker container on Kubernetes cluster needing all the resources

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing

A bit new to containers.

Want to run a python script which fails to execute on a single VM since the dataframe loads a table which is like 500 GBs and there is only like 128 GB of RAM available.

Can we somehow use a cluster of 6 Linux nodes which collectively have 1 TB of RAM by employing Kubernetes and deploy a docker container which can use all the RAM available on the cluster? Is that even a possibility?

Basically, just trying to harness the power of cluster since single node is not sufficient.

Any leads to overcome this issue?

regards,

Comment: Containers will help you run multiple identical copies of an application, but they can't affect the application logic and you can't share physical resources between containers (and especially not between nodes in Kubernetes).  Your first step probably needs to be to break up the data set into more manageable parts.  If you can create a queue of 1-GB chunks, then you could use containers to run multiple workers to do the work on multiple nodes.

Comment: @DavidMaze Is there any other way to say run the python code in a cluster without changing application logic? The challenge is we have huge datasets and initially pyspark was our choice but it does not support some open source ML libraries. The only other option is to setup another compute node with 1 TB RAM but that is not a scalable and viable solution. Any leads on overcoming this challenge via Cloudera Spark?